# How to loopback Kong's Admin API to Kong Services?

Tags: kong

I am proxying an API through Kong, but I'm concerned about Kong's Admin API and tried proxying the Admin API as another service in Kong, but I haven't been able to do it successfully.

Based on Kong's documentation, I tried using the following:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/services \
  --data name=admin-api \
  --data url=http://localhost:8001
```

While the service is created, I haven't been able to make successful calls through Postman.

Comment: can't you just expose admin endpoint to localhost only: KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN="127.0.0.1:8001" ?

Answer (score 0):

Clustering mode in kong allows you to separate the control plane (admin api) from the data plane (edge instances serving as proxy/load balancer).

https://docs.konghq.com/2.1.x/clustering/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do that because generally in PROD you dont want to expose Admin API.

Although having said that we had a requirement for test automation where we wanted to access Admin API's in NON-PROD environment & we manage it by creating a wrapper spring-boot service which exposes certain API's, which can be accessed through Kong like any other service with associated consumer.